# calculating and setting repeatitive values on Excel Spread Sheet

Tags: excel

I need help regarding calculating and setting values of hours for the dates as shown in figure. in the Excel spread sheet.
For example

```
A      B          C           D      E      F     G     H     I     J     K     L     M
Round  Est. Time  StartDate   Weeks  8/18   8/25  9/1   9/8   9/15  9/22  9/29  10/6  10/13
1st    76         8/18/2014   8      9.55   9/25  9.55  9.55  9.55  9.55  9.55  9.55  9.55
2nd    33.2       10/13/2014  2      16.6   16.6
```

Here we calculate and set values for dates  8/18   8/25  9/1   9/8   9/15  9/22  9/29  10/6  10/13 =
Est Time / Weeks = 76/8 = 9.55 so set the hours = 9.55 for next following 8 dates based on Given no. of weeks as counter.

Can you guys please help me in order to solve this. Thanks for Help in advance.
Thanks,
-San

Comment: try and better format your question!

Comment: Please see newly formatted question. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the columns are in the position given,

E3 would be

```
=IF(COLUMN()-5<$D3,$B3/$D3,"")
```

This can then be copied across the sheet.
What this does is to check how many weeks are needed to be filled in, and if that number is less than or equal to the number of weeks listed in column D, put the result of the division in the cell, otherwise put an empty string in the cell

Comment: Thanks Sean. It worked. Quick question if the D3 value is in another sheet inside same excel file then how can we refer D3 from different sheet?   =IF(COLUMN()-5<D3,B3/Sheet1!D3,"") ?

Comment: yes, that will work.  I have also edited the answer to indicate the `$` required to make the calculation columns fixed (otherwise you will get some strange results)